# VB.NET Lambda expression instead of iterator

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am fairly certain that this could be rewritten as a Lambda expression, but every attempt fails miserably.  I know, C# Lambda reads cleaner, but I'm stuck with VB.NET.  Here is the code - could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

```
For Each e As EventToMonitor In Events
    If e.TypeID = 1 Then
        If ("," & e.Values).Contains("," & b.ChoiceID & ",") Then
            Notify(cacheValues, e, "Event notification (button press)", "Button pressed: " & b.Text & " on screen: " & b.GroupBox.Text & Environment.NewLine & 
                       "User: " & cacheValues.CurrentUserName & Environment.NewLine & _
                       "Pressed at: " & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & " " & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What do you want the lambda *for* in this case? the current code is fine as-is. That said, I’d use a LINQ expression to filter (instead of `If`) and transform (instead of concatenation inside the `Notify` call), and then iterate over the result of that, calling `Notify(cacheValues, value)` for each, where `value` is the iteration variable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work if you want to convert the whole thing to lambda:

```vb
Events.Where(Function(e) e.TypeID = 1 AndAlso ("," & e.Values).Contains("," & b.ChoiceID & ",")) _
      .ToList() _
      .ForEach(Sub(e) Notify(cacheValues, e, "Event notification (button press)", "Button pressed: " & b.Text & " on screen: " & b.GroupBox.Text & Environment.NewLine & _
              "User: " & cacheValues.CurrentUserName & Environment.NewLine & _
              "Pressed at: " & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & " " & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString))
```

Honestly, though, I usually prefer to just use them to filter down results or build a collection:

```vb
Dim eventsList = Events.Where(Function(e) e.TypeID = 1 AndAlso ("," & e.Values).Contains("," & b.ChoiceID & ","))

For Each e As EventToMonitor In eventsList
    Notify(cacheValues, e, "Event notification (button press)", "Button pressed: " & b.Text & " on screen: " & b.GroupBox.Text & Environment.NewLine & 
               "User: " & cacheValues.CurrentUserName & Environment.NewLine & _
               "Pressed at: " & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & " " & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString)
Next
```

Comment: Agreed, the latter example is the route I would go too.  It's more clear that way.